# Powershell validating params for command line args

Tags: powershell, command-line

I am not understanding this.  If I put the param at the top of my script then run the script with command line and specify a user name, the user name is assigned to `$UserName`

```
Param([string]$UserName)
```

If I wrap it in a function then run it from command line:

**E.g:**  `./Script.ps1 -UserName BLAH`

It's not being assigned to `$UserName`

```
Function MainFunction
{
  Param([string]$UserName)
}
#Call Mainfunction
MainFunction;
```

Why is that?

Comment: It still doesn't work.  I do .\Test.ps1 MainFunction -UserName test and it still doesn't store the value

Comment: What makes you think it should be? Command line parameters forced into some random function, just because the function exists, overriding the fact that you explicitly call the function without any parameters? That would be .. unusable.

Comment: Sorry I am not following you?  Based on what i have read, any type of validation of the command line arguments need to be in a function.  So after the Param() you use Process{Try{test}Catch{}}

Comment: That is several different ideas mixed up together. You can write code inside a script and run it from a command line. This can include parameters and parameter validation without any functions. It can (separately) include process/try/catch blocks. Separately to that, you can write code in functions, which can also include all those things, and have nothing to do with the command line. And separately to all of those things, you can 'dot-source' or 'import-module' a script, which makes the functions inside it usable directly from the command line instead of calling the script filename.

Comment: [PowerShell scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes)

Answer (score 2):

Your code places the parameter in the scope of the function. When you run `Script.ps1 -UserName BLAH` this parameter would be passed in the scope of the script.

If you wanted to pass the variable down you would need two parameter blocks, one for the script and one for the function. Then pass script's UserName to the function as an argument of the function.

```
Param([string]$UserName)

Function MainFunction {
    Param([string]$UserName)
}

MainFunction -UserName "Chuck Norris"
```

Alternatively you could use the UserName from the script scope inside of the function by using the `$script:` to use the variable from that scope.

```
Param([string]$UserName)

Function MainFunction {
    Write-Output "Example use of $script:UserName"
}

MainFunction
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
Function MainFunction
{
  Param([string]$UserName)
  Write-Host $UserName
}
#Call Mainfunction
MainFunction  -UserName $args[0]
```

**Call From CMD:**

```
powershell -File "Script.ps1" "Chuck Norris"
```

Comment: @user1158745 Updated the solution for CMD